# how do I know which node picks up my transaction? in general, how is a node assigned to broadcast a specific transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes, node-discovery, ethernodes

How do I know what node is broadcasting my transaction to the network? how can i get more information about this node? for example, how do i know if the node is a geth or parity node? does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the blockchain concept.

Transactions are processed on all nodes. Mining determines the order of the transactions all nodes eventually agree on. This is not the same thing as a node running transactions and the rest of the network accepting its findings.

My answer over here may shed some more light on this. [how blockchain can handle the concurrency?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62160/how-blockchain-can-handle-the-concurrency/62162#62162)

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. i am wondering, though, about the pre-accepted transactions. to restate my question more clearly, there has got to be a node that picks up my transaction first, correct? Is this the node closest to me? when i send my transaction to the network through metamask, where does it physically go? do the popular nodes (metamask, mycrypto) have known physical locations?

Comment: Several details to unpack. Generally, your request goes to your own node which then broadcasts to others that you _want_ to do something. Getting picked up in a block by a miner is the critical step to _have done_ something. MetaMask uses the Infura backend which is a web service with a known endpoint. Infura is an alternative to running your own node.